# Would it be possible to route Wordpress Through an MVC Application

Tags: php, permalinks

I have a slim framework application in the root directory `/`.

I have a wordpress install in the '/blog/' child directory.

This is all fine and well as i can easily access the `/blog/` folder and any physical files.

However, the problem occurs when using the permalinks in wordpress. I haven't found a way to pass the request over to wordpress correctly.

So the first thing i tried was this:

```
$app->slim->notFound(function() use($app) { 
    //to make pretty url's work with turdpress, we must see if that request was intended for our blog route.
    if(strpos($app->slim->request->getPath(),'/blog/') !== false){
        $app->slim->response()->status(404);
    }else{
        $app->args['title'] .='404 Not Found';
        $app->args['scripts'] = 'js/404.js';
        echo $app->loadTemplate('404.twig')->render($app->args); 
    }
});
```

Here we catch requests for the blog route and return a 404 to nginx. this is what i tried to do with nginx.conf it makes sense to me but doesn't seem to work.

```
location / {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    index index.php;
    try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    error_page 404 = @default;
}
location /blog {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    index index.php;
    try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location @default{
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    index index.php;
    try_files $request_uri $request_uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

So that is what i tried, and it obviously didn't work. So i had a second idea. Maybe in the NotFound controller, i could just try to include index.php from wordpress, since this is logically the only place that permalinks would be used(or so i would assume). This is gonna be quite a bit of work, so before i go through with it i wanted to see if there were any better ideas hinging around this, or if maybe anyone else has had this problem before with *wordpress*

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like my latest idea proved correct. Simply including the index file for wordpress was enough to get permalinks working for blog posts.

```
$app->slim->notFound(function() use($app) { 
    //to make pretty url's work with turdpress, we must see if that request was intended for our blog route.
    if(strpos($app->slim->request->getPath(),'/blog/') !== false){
        include __DIR__ . '/../../blog/index.php';
    }else{
        $app->args['title'] .='404 Not Found';
        $app->args['scripts'] = 'js/404.js';
        echo $app->loadTemplate('404.twig')->render($app->args); 
    }
});
```

I am curious to know if anyone thinks this is dangerous.